# Laravel 7:Undefined variable: email

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send an email after completing the payment, with registration form data from RegisterController. I keep getting an error from my App\Mail\RegisterMail.php code

This is the function in my PaymentController.php from which I am trying to send mail:

```
public function complete(Request $request)
    {
        $signatureStatus = $this->SignatureVerify(
            $request->all()['rzp_signature'],
            $request->all()['rzp_payment_id'],
            $request->all()['rzp_order_id']
        );

        if ($signatureStatus == true) {
            $payments = new Payments;
            $payments->signature = request('rzp_signature');
            $payments->paymentId = request('rzp_payment_id');
            $payments->orderId = request('rzp_order_id');
            $payments->save();
        
            $user = Auth::user();

            $user->isPayment = 1;
            $user->save();

            // Send mail after payment is complete
            Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new RegisterMail($user->data));
            
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('payment.initiate');
        }
    }
```

This is my RegisterController.php:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'fname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'gender' => ['required', 'string'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'photo' => ['required', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg', 'max:15000'],
    }
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
     
        if (request()->hasFile('photo')) 
        {
            $photo = request()->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
            request()->file('photo')->storeAs('photos', $user->id . '/' . $photo, '');
            $user->update(['photo' => $photo]);
        }

        //When I try to send mail from here it works without any issues.
        //Mail::to('test@test.net')->send(new RegisterMail($data));

        return $user;
     }
```

This is my App\Mail\RegisterMail.php

```
class RegisterMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;
    
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    
    public function build()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $this->data['email'], 'password' => $this->data['password']])) {

            $attachments = [
                public_path('storage') . '/' . 'photos' . '/' . Auth::user()->id . '/' . Auth::user()->photo,
            ];

            $email = $this->subject('New Registration')->view('register_message')->with('data', $this->data);

            foreach ($attachments as $filePath) {
                $email->attach($filePath);
            }
        }
        return $email;
    }
}
```

**[Stack Trace](https://flareapp.io/share/A7EYKq7r)**

Comment: which line you get this error ?

Comment: What's your question about this? If the error message from the title applies: what have you tried to resolve it - like: defining `$data`?

Comment: I want to send all the user data along with the attachment to an email address from the `PaymentController.php`.

Comment: It is an error in send_mail function where you are using $data variable which is not exists. Then obviously the PHP return error of undefined variable "data"

Comment: Simply put print_r or var_dump at PaymentController.php before line number 71 for $data and check why it is undefined.

Comment: Man, I think you need to learn the basics of PHP first. anyway use var_dump as var_dump($data);

Comment: I already did that, its the same thing, I get the same error, I have tried `dd($data), var_dump($data), print_r ($data)`, I even tried adding a constructor like `public $data;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }`

Comment: I am getting null values

Comment: In your function you need the param,  like `public function send_mail(Request $request, $data)` so you need to pass the `$data` on the `send_mail()` function too

Comment: @sta I tried that but now I am getting this error `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController::complete(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: Yes, because it accept now argument. I already told you need to pass $data

Comment: I tried `public function complete(Request $request, $data = '')`, I am getting another error from the `RegisterMail.php` code `Undefined variable: email`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a redirect in RegisterController.php and pass the data this way:

```
return redirect()->route('PaymentControllerRouteName',[$data]);
```

Or simply create and trigger an event (trigger it in RegisterController). You can learn more about events here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events

In this case, I would use an event because it is reusable.